# Retrofit 2 returning GET response on a POST query

Tags: android, api, retrofit2

I am getting a response code of 200 and the response body is returning a list of all the other entries in the database.I have tried using Volley as well,but getting the same response.Is this a server side issue?

Base URL:http://ankitkaushal.000webhostapp.com/

ApiServiceInterface:

```
@POST("API")
Call <ResponseBody> saveCard(@Body card_attributes card);
```

Call METHOD:

```
  public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
           if(response.isSuccessful())
           {
               try {
                   Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Card Saved!"+response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   Log.i("success"," CODE: "+response.code()+"BODY: "+response.body().string());
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               isSaved=true;
           }
           else{
               Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Error Occured,Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               Log.i("saving error",""+response.errorBody());}
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
           Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "Error Occured,Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           Log.i("saving error",""+t.getMessage());
       }
   });
```

Comment: how do your routes look?

Comment: I am pretty much a beginner,what do you mean by routes?

Comment: "API/" is a route , POST is method , you need server somewhere that has route "API/" to handle your request and give back response. Do you have server or API to talk to?

Comment: Oh okay thanks for specifying.I do have an API over a MySQL database.